# Shared Element Transition to ImageView works on exit, not smooth on enter

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-transitions

As you can see from the video when the image is clicked in my `Recyclerview` it is not smooth when transitioning to the new activity. When i click back to go back to original activity the transition is smooth. How can i make the transition smooth when opening activity?

[Video of issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jclu3xjm08ksfyf/screen-recording_20150717-174228.mp4?dl=0)

Here's the code launching the activity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), WallpaperFullActivity.class);

View sharedView = v.findViewById(R.id.wall_image);
String transitionName = "wall_trans";
ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions = 
  ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), sharedView, transitionName);

myIntent.putExtra(WallpaperFullActivity.BUNDLE_TAG, mDataWalls.get(i));
ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(), myIntent, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
```

Answer (score 2):

Seeing the names of your variables, I guess you are transitioning to a ImageView with a high resolution image. A problem might be, that the loading of the image takes some time and so the final position and size of the ImageView is not known at the time of transitioning, thus making the transition jerky. Consider postponining your transition with `Activity.postponeEnterTransition()` and start it with `Activity.startPostponedEnterTransition()` when the image is loaded. For more information, see [this blog entry](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/03/activity-postponed-shared-element-transitions-part3b.html).